# Can I take the average of two standardized variables

Tags: normalization, standardization, mean

I am wondering if there are any theoretical problems with taking the average of two standardized variables. Suppose I want to combine two variables to have a single measure. I could create an index by using weighted averages or PCA. I was wondering if there are any theoretical impediments against standardizing each variable and then taking the arithmetic average.

Comment: It's just a case of whether it's useful, I think.

Comment: Edited to mean standardizing.

Comment: @MFadic, thank you for the edit. I will delete my previous comment (and this one, after you see it).

Comment: This is more of a curiosity than anything else, the average of two standardized random variables (which are measured in "standard deviations away from the mean") is actually unitless. I can post my derivation if anyone is interested

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think you would run into major problems.  The first one is that the average of two Standardized variables could be absent of meaning.  Let's say variable A has a standardized value of - 3.0 and variable B a standardized value of + 3.0.  Their average is 0.  The average has essentially wiped out the fact that both variables had an extreme value 3 standard deviations away from their respective Mean.  The second problem is also associated with absence of meaning when you will average those two variables that have completely different scale.  Let's say variable A has a scale that is 100 times greater than variable B.  If you average variable A with variable B, the average of variable A at 2.0 and variable B at 0.0 is the same as the average of variable A at 0.0 and variable B at 2.0.  But, when you understand the underlying compositions of those two different averages they have a completely different meaning that gets masked by their identical average.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the explanation. The main reason for this question was on the "meaning" part of your explanation which I would like to understand better. To make the problem more concrete lets say we want to to grade students who have taken a set of different tests. Problem #1 will exist even if we take averages or other moments. This point i understand. Regarding problem #2, if what I am trying to measure is relative (ordinary) performance, and I understand the scales, then the standardization and averaging  of those variables (or tests) should give me such  measure, right?

Comment: If I understand your situation, the numbers you are dealing with are ordinal of a rank like nature (1st, 2nd, 3d, etc.).  Therefore, they would be on the same scale and this second issue would be avoided.  However, I am not sure if you can standardize such variables or if you did what would be the meaning of such standardized variables.  The standard deviation of an ordinal number seems like a strange concept.